# Two automorphisms with the same orbits

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are two automorphisms of $G$ of order $p$, where $p$ is a prime number. If $\phi$ and $\psi$ satisfy the following condition, is the subgroup generated by $\phi$ equal to the subgroup generated by $\psi$?

"for every $g\in G$, $\{\phi(g),\cdots,\phi^p(g)\}=\{\psi(g),\cdots,\psi^p(g)\}$"

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counterexample, let $G=C_2^3$ be elementary abelian of order $8$. Then any element of ${\rm Aut}(G) \cong {\rm GL}(3,2)$ of order $7$ has a single orbit on the non-identity elements of $G$.

Now ${\rm GL}(3,2)$ has $8$ subgroups of order $7$, so just take $\phi$ and $\psi$ from distinct subgroups of order $7$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your nice example.